# Group Javascript object based on Array Object list

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, grouping

I'm trying to find a way to convert this list of objects based on the group `array`. The tricky part I've found is iterating through the group Array and applying the object to more than one place if there are multiple groups.

I'm also trying to ignore any group that does not belong to anything. I've tried using the `reduce` function but I cannot get the iteration through the group array.

```
  let cars = 
    [
      {
        "group":[],
        "name": "All Makes",
        "code": ""
      },
      {
        "group":["Group A"],
        "name": "BMW",
        "code": "X821"
      },
      {
        "group":["Group B"],
        "name": "Audi",
        "code": "B216"
      },
      {
        "group":["Group B"],
        "name": "Ford",
        "code": "P385"    
      },
      {
        "group":["Group B", "Group C"],
        "name": "Mercedes",
        "code": "H801"
      },
      {
        "group":["Group C"],
        "name": "Honda",
        "code": "C213"
      }
    ]
```

To become this:

```
let cars = {
    "Group A": [
      {
        name: "BMW",
        code: "X821",
      }
    ],
    "Group B": [
      {
        name: "Audi", 
        code: "B216"
      },
      {
        name: "Ford", 
        code: "P385"
      },
      {
        name: "Mercedes",
        code: "H801"
      }
    ],
    "Group C":[
      {
        name: "Mercedes",
        code: "H801"
      },
      {
        name:"Honda", 
        code: "C213"
      }
    ]
  };
```

I already tried using reduce to accomplish this but the grouping doesn't replicate if it's in more than one group.

```
let result = cars.reduce(function(x, {group, name}){
  return Object.assign(x, {[group]:(x[group] || [] ).concat({group, name})})
}, {});
```

Any pointers to help with this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `.reduce()` to loop through each car object in `cars`. For each `group` array for a given car, you can then use `.forEach()` to then add that group as a key to the accumulator. If the group has already been set in the accumulator, you can grab the grouped array of objects, otherwise, you can create a new array `[]`. Once you have an array you can then add the object to the array using `.concat()`. Since we're using `.forEach()` on the `group` array, it won't add the object to the accumulated object if it is empty as `.forEach()` won't iterate over an empty array.

See example below:

```js
const cars = [{ "group":[], "name": "All Makes", "code": "" }, { "group":["Group A"], "name": "BMW", "code": "X821" }, { "group":["Group B"], "name": "Audi", "code": "B216" }, { "group":["Group B"], "name": "Ford", "code": "P385" }, { "group":["Group B", "Group C"], "name": "Mercedes", "code": "H801" }, { "group":["Group C"], "name": "Honda", "code": "C213" } ];
          
const res = cars.reduce((acc, {group, ...r}) => {
  group.forEach(key => {
    acc[key] = (acc[key] || []).concat({...r}); // copy r so it is a different reference for each grouped array
  });
  return acc;
}, {});
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

Some basic approach. @Nick's is much better.

```js
let cars = [{
    "group": [],
    "name": "All Makes",
    "code": ""
  },
  {
    "group": ["Group A"],
    "name": "BMW",
    "code": "X821"
  },
  {
    "group": ["Group B"],
    "name": "Audi",
    "code": "B216"
  },
  {
    "group": ["Group B"],
    "name": "Ford",
    "code": "P385"
  },
  {
    "group": ["Group B", "Group C"],
    "name": "Mercedes",
    "code": "H801"
  },
  {
    "group": ["Group C"],
    "name": "Honda",
    "code": "C213"
  }
]
let newCars = {};
cars.forEach(o => {
  o.group.forEach(g => {
    if (!newCars[g])
      newCars[g] = [];
    newCars[g].push({
      name: o.name,
      code: o.code
    });
  });
});
console.log(newCars);
```